# PySpark Group and apply UDF row by row operation

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataset that contains 'tag' and 'date'. I need to group the data by 'tag' (this is pretty easy), then within each group count the number of row that the date for them is smaller than the date in that specific row. I basically need to loop over the rows after grouping the data. I don't know how to write a UDF which takes care of that in PySpark. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Best to give sample dataset and expected result.

Comment: can you share sample input and output ? from your question it is difficult to derive logic

Comment: would be good to provide an example. But you should not need a loop nor a UDF for that. Using loops in pysparks break the logic of pyspark, as you can't distribute a job in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

you need an aggregation ?

df.groupBy("tag").agg({"date":"min"})

what about that ?